# Firebase storage credentials missing for googleapis.com issue

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-api, gcloud

I am using firebase to store and see images from my website.
but not able to open files from my firebase storage bucket even it has storage admin role on cloud google.

I am able to see images on directly cloud google console but not from firebase console.

I am getting this response below.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.internal.cloud.usersettings.v1alpha1.BasicTypesService.GetUserSetting",
          "service": "cloudusersettings-pa.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

note: even link over firebase is not opening with token. It was working 24 hours before. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/news-26417.appspot.com/o/--4720109.jpeg?alt=media&token=a7475fec-3fe5-48e7-8f99-6e9c57e462b9

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

**Update**: from what I understand from our support team and other channels this problem has been solved by the providers now. If it still happens for you, reach out to your provider/ISP and to the support team I linked below.

---

Old answer

Since yesterday we've had reports from some developers (mostly in Turkey) being unable to access Cloud Storage.

I recommend testing with another connection to verify if you're in the same situation. If it works on another connection, you should probably reach out to your ISP to see if they can explain the problem.

I'd also [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) who are tracking the issue.