# Firebase Storage stopped downloading files for some users

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Everything was working fine. I did not change any code. Today some of my users can not download files from firebase storage and others can download the files.

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation retry limit has been exceeded.
       at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.completeTask(NetworkRequest.java:539)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:85)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by java.io.IOException
   at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:113)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
   at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: It's hard to be certain, but I recommend checking of the affected users are all in the same region. Since yesterday I'm seeing reports from developers in Turkey who are having trouble accessing storage, so if your users are in that region too - it might point to the same root cause. Also see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055973/209103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055919/209103).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your answer. Yes our users who get the error are from Turkey. I already reported the issue to Firebase Support and waiting for their answer.